# IIS7: Sharing Sessions Between Applications With State Server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I have my default website in IIS7 bound to an ASP.NET application.  This application is using the ASP.NET State Server to store session data. I would like to add an additional ASP.NET MVC application to this website.  Is it possible to share the session between these two applications using the state server? I've read that there are ways to do it storing session data in SQL Server, but I can't find any documentation on doing it with the state server.

Thanks,
Nathan

Answer (score 2):

Best advice I have to to switch to SQL Server for the session state store.  It's not difficult to set up if you already have SQL Available and use the following technique:

[Sharing sessions across applications using the ASP.NET Session State Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868316/sharing-sessions-across-applications-using-the-asp-net-session-state-service)

Answer (score 1):

For this situation you are probably best to write your own custom session state provider that runs on a SQL database.

details are here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479034.aspx

the reason i'd write a custom provider is because simply settings up an SQL session provider will not be enough as the applications will use different session keys and therefore will not share state between them. by writing your own session provider you can have fine grained control over the whole process and therefore override the checks in place using the default sql session provider.