# ASP.Net C# Sharing Session Across Multiple App Pools

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, session-state

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can’t I share Session state between 2 web apps with StateServer? What am I missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292359/why-cant-i-share-session-state-between-2-web-apps-with-stateserver-what-am-i-m)

I am trying to maintain the session state across a web application where a user may login in to www.domain.com and at some point in their browsing experience be redirected to ww2.domain.com on a different server for load balancing reasons. What is the best way to maintain a users session in this instance?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use [SQL Server session state](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604?wa=wsignin1.0) rather that in-process which is the default.

Comment: I have already done this,but I can't seem to get the sessions to share. The applications are on two separate servers. The issue is that they do not have the same appId, not allowing them to access the same session data.

Answer (score 0):

You need out-proc session management.

Hundreds of articles/techniques can be found on dear internet. One of them 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ganesh.nataraj/ASPdotNETSessionState09212005235624PM/ASPdotNETSessionState.aspx