# How can Use Session For all My different ASP.NET MVC Projects

Tags: asp.net, session, asp.net-mvc-5

I have Case which my `ASP.NET` MVC Projects separated in single project. How can use one session to Authorize all project Users ?

What i do Now is Creating base Controller & Validate on Session On ActionExcuting Method but when navigate to another Project Session is gone.

Hint i dont need Areas in Projects

2- Cookie is not suitable for me

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first option is session state in [SQL server](https://support.microsoft.com/pl-pl/kb/317604)

second option make use of [Session State Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732412(v=ws.10).aspx).

both options may require some hacks to work. there are many questions and answers on stackoverflow about this.

Comment: Thanks For Your Reply any Links For this Options

Comment: basics you can find on https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754032(v=ws.10).aspx . 
About hacks look for "session state server two applications" or "sql server session state two applications" 
examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130239/sharing-sql-server-session-state-across-web-applications
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292359/why-cant-i-share-session-state-between-2-web-apps-with-stateserver-what-am-i-m