# How to encrypt one entry in web.config

Tags: asp.net, encryption, web-config

ASP.NET 4

I've used [RSA key encryption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650304.aspx#paght000006_webfarmscenarios) for connection strings in web.config on my web farm. However, there's one more custom password entry that I'd like to encrypt. How should I encrypt it with RSA key without having the rest configurations being encrypted. Please advise, thanks.

Example:

```
  <appSettings>
        ...
    <add key="Host" value="www.foo.com" />
    <add key="Token" value="qwerqwre" />
    <add key="AccountId" value="123" />
    <add key="DepartmentId" value="456" />
    <add key="Password" value="asdfasdf" />
    <add key="SessionEmail" value="foo@foo.com" />
    <add key="DefaultFolder" value="789" />
  </appSettings>
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You could put the password into a separate section and encrypt this section only. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="secureAppSettings" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    </configSections>

    <appSettings>
        <add key="Host" value="www.foo.com" />
        <add key="Token" value="qwerqwre" />
        <add key="AccountId" value="123" />
        <add key="DepartmentId" value="456" />
        <add key="SessionEmail" value="foo@foo.com" />
        <add key="DefaultFolder" value="789" />  
    </appSettings>

    <secureAppSettings>
        <add key="Password" value="asdfasdf" />
    </secureAppSettings>  
</configuration>
```

and then (note that I am using DPAPI in my example so adapt the provider for RSA):

```
aspnet_regiis -pef secureAppSettings . -prov DataProtectionConfigurationProvider
```

Once encrypted the file will look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="secureAppSettings" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    </configSections>

    <appSettings>
        <add key="Host" value="www.foo.com" />
        <add key="Token" value="qwerqwre" />
        <add key="AccountId" value="123" />
        <add key="DepartmentId" value="456" />
        <add key="SessionEmail" value="foo@foo.com" />
        <add key="DefaultFolder" value="789" />  
    </appSettings>

    <secureAppSettings configProtectionProvider="DataProtectionConfigurationProvider">
        <EncryptedData>
            <CipherData>
                <CipherValue>AQAAANCMnd.......</CipherValue>
            </CipherData>
        </EncryptedData>
    </secureAppSettings>  
</configuration>
```

The way you would access those settings in your application once the file is encrypted is still the same and completely transparent:

```
var host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Host"];
var password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];
```

Comment: How come it's not ConfigurationManager.secureAppSettings["Password"]? What makes .NET can treat that secureAppSettings section as part of appSettings?

Comment: @Stan, it uses a `NameValueSectionHandler`.

Comment: I am not able to retrieve the value of "Password" in from "secureAppSettings" section using "ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];" in .net 3.5 asp.net website.

Comment: Try using the following:                                             var section = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("secureAppSettings") as NameValueCollection;
var configPwd = section["LoginPassword"];

Comment: This almost worked for me. I had to use a different type in the configSections section tag:     <section name="secureAppSettings" type="System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection, System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />

Comment: This type worked for me too.  In the code, I just call it a NameValueCollection var section =
                (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("secureAppSettings");
            var s = section[key];

Answer (score 14):

In c# and .Net 4.5 I had to use this to read the encrypted setting:

```
string password = ((System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("secureAppSettings"))["Password"];
```

but otherwise works a treat.

Comment: This is not an answer, it is addition to an answer

Answer (score 8):

You can't encrypt a single entry - the infrastructure only allows for encryption of whole config sections.

One option is to place the entry in its own config section and encrypt that.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to encrypt a subsection? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504301/encrypt-a-subsection-of-web-config

Comment: This is not true: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/gaurav/2013/12/15/encrypting-section-of-config-file-using-aspnet_regiis-exe-the-configuration-for-physical-path-web-config-cannot-be-opened/

Comment: @RyanMendoza - you need to read that article again. A single **node**, or single **entry** cannot be encrypted - the whole section needs to be encrypted.

Comment: @Allen - guess I'll have to disagree. The above answer shows how to move an entry to a section and then encrypt that section... which is basically my second sentence.