# Impersonate and encrypt user account to call Web Service from ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, web-services, encryption, impersonation

I have an **ASP.NET Web Forms** application and I need to impersonate an account to connect to a **Web Service**. The application always connects with the same account and has to be encrypted.

The client is `MyWebServiceClient()` my code is:

```
MyWebService.MyWebServiceClient client = new MyWebService.MyWebServiceClient();

client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);
```

And it works perfectly. The problem is how to encrypt these data. Is it possible to do it inside the web.config within the web service binding?

```
<security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
    transport clientCredentialType="Windows" realm="" />
<security>
```

If that is the case, how can I retrieve them from code? Thanks

Comment: What do you want to encrypt? The credentials in webconfig? The traffic between your application and the webservice?

Comment: Thanks! I want to encrypt the credentials in the webconfig

Answer (score 1):

Add your credentials to the app settings section. Then encrypt that section using aspnet_regis tool

[How to encrypt one entry in web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224732/how-to-encrypt-one-entry-in-web-config)

http://www.dotnetprofessional.com/blog/post/2008/03/03/Encrypt-sections-of-WebConfig-or-AppConfig.aspx

Best regards asere.

Comment: Thanks! what shall I put in the security section of the web.config as client credentials?

Comment: The kind of client credentials your ws is configured to receive...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.httptransportsecurity.clientcredentialtype.aspx