# How to encript connectionstring section into the web config

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, web-config

I tried to use integrated security SSIP but it takes anonymous user so any developer can access the database. So anybody have any solution for this problem?

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="Local2" connectionString="Data Source=ADMIN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=NEOPLAST_LIVE;username="abc" password="****" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: [How to encrypt one entry in web.config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224732/how-to-encrypt-one-entry-in-web-config)

Comment: just encrypt the two strings

Comment: @Jonesy - and where do you put the key?

Comment: @HenkHolterman you should put your key inside the code. Just compile it.

Comment: @Gandarez - that is a possibility, used a lot. But not very safe. Big steel door and the key under the mat.