# Encrypting one element of the web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, encryption, web-config

I've been **encrypting and decrypting** my **webconfig** by following this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/53tyfkaw(v=vs.100).asp

And everything works just fine, I encrypted the *appSettings* section 
of my **web.config**.

I use this command to **encrypt** the whole "appSettings" section:

**aspnet_regiis -pef "appSettings" "path" -prov  "RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider"**

> appSettings>
>
> add key="remote" value="false" />
>
> add key="TimeZone" value="5" />
>
> add key="ErrorLevel" value="Low" />
>
> add key="password" value="XXXXX" />
>
> /appSettings>

But now I need to **encrypt** not the whole section but just an element.
Lets say I only need to encrypt this element:

> add key="password" value="XXXXX" />

Any ideas about what is the command to encrypt just en element of a section ?

Regards.

Comment: This might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224732/how-to-encrypt-one-entry-in-web-config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I just had to create another section and write there the element, and then encrypt that section. Simple as that

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there isn't one.  You have to encrypt the value and store it in the config file manually.  I don't believe there is an ability for singularity like you describe.