# Encrypt a subsection of web.config

Tags: asp.net, encryption, web-config

I would like to encrypt a *subsection* of a web.config (not a top level *section*). for example:

```
  <SomeSection>
    <settings>
      <add name="foo" value="bar" />
    </settings>
    <secretSettings>
      <add name="password" value="foobar" />
    </secretSettings>
  </SomeSection>
```

Is there a way to encrypt the `<secretSettings>` subsection similar to [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224732/how-to-encrypt-one-entry-in-web-config/6224769)? Note I cannot simply move the subsection into a main section because there is code which is outside of my control that is currently using it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to encrypt one entry in web.config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224732/how-to-encrypt-one-entry-in-web-config)

Comment: @OliverSpryn - that question and corresponding answers are demonstrating how to encrypt a section, not a subsection. I even already linked to that question in mine, so obviously it isn't a duplicate.