# Share Session Variables between projects C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, share

Is there any way to share Session or any type of variables with their own data between projects?

I have a solution which has 2+ projects in which I have an object called `Users`, you login on the first project and I place the whole Users object with all the data in a `Session["User"]` variable, and I'll like to later access on a different project but having the same stored data.

As if in my first project a variable has a value = 1 the second project can read it in the second project in the same solution and still have the same value.

EDIT:
Found a solution to this within the next link:

[Sharing sessions across applications using the ASP.NET Session State Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868316/sharing-sessions-across-applications-using-the-asp-net-session-state-service/3151315#3151315)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438912/share-session-between-two-web-sites-using-asp-net-and-state-server).

Comment: "Projects" is a design-time concept, once code is compiled it all runs in the same process space, and sharing data depends on how those components connect to each other. Is it possible, absolutely.