# Session not saved for the domains with/without www ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, session, webforms, dns, hosting

This might be a possible duplicate, but as I none of the answers were working for me from those portals, I'm posting the question again.

I have a website and when I'm trying to test the session data within this website by giving two different domain names in the URL.

I'm attaching screenshots for brief explanation.
[image]

When I log in to the URL ssfound.com, the session is saved and my login details are displayed.

When I open www.ssfound.com then the session is unable to get htese login details.

I searched in the internet and found few solutions but none of them are working.
I tested after adding it into config file , but below doesn't work

```
<httpCookies domain=".ssfound.com"/>

<httpCookies domain="ssfound.com"/>
```

I even tried `<sessionstate cookieless="true"/>` and mode = InProc but neither these work.

please don't mark it as duplicate, because I tried the above [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438912/share-session-between-two-web-sites-using-asp-net-and-state-server) in from the stackoverflow community & they didn't work from me.

Comment: You should never use cookieless sessions.

Comment: Yes mason, adding cookieless actually caused another problem while uploading a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sites ssfound.com and www.ssfound.com are considered as two different sites, similar to http and https.

Choose between non-www or www and always redirect users to your desired url, this also help you in terms of SEO, analytics, inbound links, etc.

You can use below c# code (in global file) to convert non www site users to www site.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!Request.Url.Host.StartsWith ("www") && !Request.Url.IsLoopback)
   {
      UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder (Request.Url);
      builder.Host = "www." + Request.Url.Host;
      Response.StatusCode = 301;
      Response.AddHeader ("Location", builder.ToString ());
      Response.End ();
   }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the solution, this is working. But, I've to check if this is affecting the existing functionality or not.