# Sharing session between Asp.Net and Asp.Net Core application

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, asp.net-core, session-state

Is there any way to do this?
I have two different applications :

1. Asp.Net MVC application - A
2. Asp.Net Core WebApi application - B

From A, on an event,

- I want to send data to B,   Create a session at B,   Store some data
- Return
- Now, In the same browser session if the same event occurs again,
- send data to B
- retrieve the session value at B which was set in the first request
- update data
- return

I can make an AJAX call from A to B, the issue I am facing here is on every request it generates a new session.

I understand, that cookie is set in the browser from Application A, and so every time it calls Application B, a new session is generated.

Can I achieve this using out-proc session mode?

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438912/share-session-between-two-web-sites-using-asp-net-and-state-server

Comment: What kind of information A and B are passing back and forward?

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box solution in .NET to handle this scenario. Howerver, if you are willing to use a distributed cache for sessions caching, [NCache](https://www.alachisoft.com/resources/docs/ncache/prog-guide/aspnet-session-sharing.html) definitely seems to have an answer to this.