# How to Pass values from one project to another Using ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have 2 ASP.NET MVC projects.Assume Project names are A , B. In A project i have a form. I want to fill that form and submit. If i click on submit that data should goes to B projects controller. Following is my A project controller. How can I call B projects Controller and pass those form details to that controller?

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Contact([Bind(Include = "UserId , CompanyName , Name , Email , phone , message")] ContactModel model)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {

        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Can you use sessions?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438912/share-session-between-two-web-sites-using-asp-net-and-state-server