# Is State Server Session data separate between IIS websites?

Tags: c#, session, iis

A problem with our application is that it stores "work" variables into the Session and also on the form in an attempt to improve performance/laziness. This is ingrained into the application.

We have a problem where this data is lost after a deployment and the end user must refresh the page or they receive exceptions.

I am looking at changing our Session State from In process to a State Server. We have multiple instances of our web application running for different users.

My question is, is the State Server data separate or will there be a potential to mix between instances? Our admin users may log into multiple instances but typically clients only log into the instance they are primarily running on.

Comment: Is your issue solved?

If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

In- Proc: Session state is stored locally in the memory of the ASP.NET worker process.

StateServer: Session state is stored outside of the ASP.NET worker process and is managed by a Windows service. The location of this service is specified by stateConnectionString attribute.

SQLServer: Session state is stored outside of the ASP.NET worker process in a SQL Server database. The location of this database is specified using the sqlConnectionString attribute.

You can use StateServer or SQLServer to share the session between two instances.

You could refer to the below link for more detail:

[Sharing sessions across applications using the ASP.NET Session State Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868316/sharing-sessions-across-applications-using-the-asp-net-session-state-service)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36145075

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms525037(v=vs.90)

Comment: There's a lot there that does not answer my question. My direct question is: If I have two separate websites using the same State Server will the data be segregated or mixed?