# How to cross session in diff application but in same domain?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

How to cross session in diff application but in same domain?

For example .. there are two website URL.

```
http://test.com.tw/FirstApp/Index

http://test.com.tw/SecondApp/Index
```

When First Website Set Session

```
Session["TempID"] = "Temp String"
```

How can second website to get `Session["TempID"]`'s Value?

I have try to get the value in second website..

but it's null...

Comment: By default session cannot be shared between different applications. You may found some special way to share session between application. But not all of them work. Some of them  are feasible in theory, but there are problems in actual operation. So I recommend you to use SQL server to store session as @iamdlm said. It is safer and more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

The "seemingly official" way is to [use SQL Server session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868316/sharing-sessions-across-applications-using-the-asp-net-session-state-service/3151315#3151315).

In case you can't use SQL server for any reason, then you can tweak the IIS applications so that you can [use Out-of-process session](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36145075/3990896).