# Where are the session variables saved?

Tags: asp.net, session, memory, session-variables

Where exactly are session variables saved? Cookies? Server memory?

Again where are Application variables saved?

Comment: That looks like more than one question.

Comment: @Chris: May be. Does it matter?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Variables put into Session are stored wherever the configured `SessionStateProvider` is configured to store them.

The default `SessionStateProvider`uses what's referred to as In Process (`InProc`) Session and the storage location for this is in server memory, inside the memory space of the ASP.NET worker process.

You can configure your own `SessionStateProvider` to store Session variables elsewhere, such as out of process, in a database.

Application variables are stored in `ApplicationState` which is also stored in the memory space of the ASP.NET worker process. Unlike Session State, Application State applies to all users and sessions. As far as I am aware, There is no configuration to store ApplicationState elsewhere; if you need to store lots of application data then you may want to look at [ASP.NET Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178597.aspx).

Comment: Could you please provide an example how I could store my own session variable elsewhere? 
Also can the session variables still be accessed in the same way?

Comment: @NevilleNazerane Take a look at the in-built `SqlSessionStateStore` in `system.Web` assembly; open it in Reflector, DotPeek or similar to see how it's implemented. Alternatively, you can get an idea of how to implement one here https://github.com/dnauck/AspSQLProvider/blob/master/src/NauckIT.PostgreSQLProvider/PgSessionStateStoreProvider.cs which is an implementation of a Sql Session stored in Postgres database

Comment: I got what i needed from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3151315/991609). It has got good explanation. Thank you

Comment: Can we store the session variables on hard disk of the server?  #interviewQuestions

Comment: @Lakshay you can store _Session_ wherever you like by writing your own `SessionStateProvider`

Answer (score 12):

**Session variables** are stored on **Server Memory and Disk**  as **Application Variables** are.

From [ASP.NET documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx):

> ASP.NET session state supports several
>   storage options for session variables.
>   Each option is identified as a
>   session-state Mode type. The default
>   behavior is to store session variables
>   in the memory space of the ASP.NET
>   worker process. However, you can also
>   specify that session state should be
>   stored in a separate process, in a SQL
>   Server database, or in a custom data
>   source. If you do not want session
>   state enabled for your application,
>   you can set the session mode to Off.

Answer (score 4):

For an InProc session, variables are stored locally in memory of ASP.NET worker process. Same goes for application state.