# Session State shares session across subdomain, VB.NET website C# MVC 4 Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, session

I am trying to share a session from a main VB.Net Website and a subdomain C# MVC 4.

I have the same ASP.NET_SessionId Cookie present for both sites and in the Immediate Debugger I can see both Session objects have the same SessionID. However when I set a session from the VB.Net website, `Session("TestSession") = "SimpleString"`, if i call the Session Object in the Immediate Window from the MVC Application the Count is 0.

This is also the case if i set a session in the MVC Application it is not found in the VB.Net Website.

Preferably I would like to use StateServer Mode but I have read that only SQLServer Mode works for cross domain support.

Here is the web.config that is present in both sites

```
<httpCookies domain=".example.localhost"/>
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="Data Source=(local);Integrated Security=True" />
<machineKey validationKey="XXX" decryptionKey="XXX" validation="SHA1" compatibilityMode="Framework20SP1" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve the problem as well as adding the web.config settings I had to add a couple of lines to the Application_Start from the global.asax. This had to be added to both sites.

**C#**

```
FieldInfo runtimeInfo = typeof(HttpRuntime).GetField("_theRuntime", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
HttpRuntime theRuntime = (HttpRuntime)runtimeInfo.GetValue(null);
FieldInfo appNameInfo = typeof(HttpRuntime).GetField("_appDomainAppId", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
appNameInfo.SetValue(theRuntime, "MyApplicationName");
```

**VB.Net**

```
Dim runtimeInfo As System.Reflection.FieldInfo = GetType(HttpRuntime).GetField("_theRuntime", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.[Static] Or System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic)
Dim theRuntime As HttpRuntime = DirectCast(runtimeInfo.GetValue(Nothing), HttpRuntime)
Dim appNameInfo As System.Reflection.FieldInfo = GetType(HttpRuntime).GetField("_appDomainAppId", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic)
appNameInfo.SetValue(theRuntime, "MyApplicationName")
```

Comment: This won't work if the applications are on different subdomains.

Comment: @MichaelFry This was deployed to different subdomains and worked correctly.

Comment: You're right, it does work. Not sure what was wrong before... Oh well, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You should use a cookie and not a session variable. Session variables are saved on the server so when you goto another server, it will not have your session variable.

See this SO question for more detail: [where-are-the-session-variables-saved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526349/where-are-the-session-variables-saved)

Comment: You are incorrect, you can use sessionState to create a sessions server that the website connect to for their sessions... as it happens i have solved this problem and it works

Comment: @AshleyMedway If you have solved this issue, you should put it as an answer and then mark it as answered. That way others that have your same issue can find thier answer.