# Where is session store ? (ExpressJS)

Tags: node.js, express, session

I'm learning ExpressJS, and I want to make a Register-Login system.

I'm reading about `express-session` and it seems kind of easy to use but I wonder,

- by default, where does it store session for each user ?
- And when do those session get deleted ?

Can U guys give me some blog post about this ? Thank U

Comment: If you don't use external store, it is stored in memory. And when you restart the app, it will be lost.

Comment: refer this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526349/where-are-the-session-variables-saved

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you don't supply express-session with a storage mechanism, then it just uses a lightweight memory store.   Thus, it is not persisted across server restarts.

From [the doc](https://github.com/expressjs/session#store):

> store
>
> The session store instance, defaults to a new MemoryStore instance.

The `MemoryStore` comes with these warnings:

> Warning The default server-side session storage, MemoryStore, is purposely not designed for a production environment. It will leak memory under most conditions, does not scale past a single process, and is meant for debugging and developing.
>
> For a list of stores, see [compatible session stores](https://github.com/expressjs/session#compatible-session-stores).