# I want to use Javascript to call .NET WebService, How to limit the access?

Tags: javascript, web-services, authentication

I have a .net webservice like `http://tempurl.org/webservice.asmx`
I want to call it using Javascript, maybe some jquery lib.
Q1: How to limit the access only to myself?
Q2: or How to implement a role based authentication.

Edit:
I want to deploy the webservice independently like:

```
ProjectA
ProjectB
ProjectWebService
```

I need People login in ProjectA and ProjectB and can use ProjectWebService.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just a suggestion, as you know theres many ways to skin a cat so heres one.
Firstly enable session state across calls to the service using

```
 [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
```

Then have a web service method for login that saves the user details to the session, this supports the standard Membership provider for asp.net, **warning sample code**

```
 public bool Login(string userName, string password)
 {
      //validate login
      var user = Membership.GetUser(userName);
      var valid = Membership.ValidateUser(user.UserName, password));
      if (valid)
          HttpContext.Current.Session["user"] = user;
      return valid;
 }
```

Then you can in a web service method validate against the user.

```
public void SomeServerMethod()
{
    var user = HttpContext.Current.Session["user"]; 

    if (user == null)
         throw new Exception("Please login first");

     if (user.IsInRole("FooRole")
             DoStuff();
     else
         throw new Exception("Seriously? dude you dont have those rights");

 }
```

To counter network easedropping best go to Https, good luck :)

Comment: New problem please. I have 2 projects under 1 solution. The user login in Project1 and use webservice in Project2. The `session` seems not to be carried on.

Comment: Are you hosting two sites? how are the projects accessed? can you explain a bit more...

Comment: Something like: `user.site.com`, `admin.site.com`, `webservice.site.com`. One site, three different modules.

Comment: check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868316/sharing-sessions-across-applications-using-the-asp-net-session-state-service