# How to send the session data from one application to another application with in the same solution?

Tags: asp.net, session, c#-4.0, session-state, mvp

I am creating the session in class file of the first application and need to access the same session  in second application both of the applications are presented in the same solution.
when i am trying to do this session in second application  getting null but session contain data in the first application.

In first Application

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["key1"] = "a";
```

In second application

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Session["key1"]!= null) //i am getting session as null hear
```

How is it possible to send the session data from one application to another application with in the same solution?

please some one help me..

Comment: Exact duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2868316/30594

Comment: I dont want any database call

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't want to use DB?

Comment: Check this link http://weblogs.asp.net/lichen/archive/2011/10/05/sharing-session-state-over-multiple-asp-net-applications-with-asp-net-state-server.aspx . But I would prefer not going down that approach.

Comment: I am trying to store some URL in that session and I want the same URL on my second application. without using session if is there any better way to get then plz tell me.

Comment: You can encrypt and store the information in a cookie and read the same in the second application. This will work if your applications run in the same domain. Also, ensure the url passed cannot be tampered and is safe from replay attacks. Other way is to pass this encrypted information using query string / cross page postback. But what ever you do, safe guard it from replay attacks by attaching time stamp before encrypting and compare the same after decrypting.