# Asp.net session state sqlserver sharing between two application

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, iis

I created two web applications "First" and "second" using session mode sql server to share session from one application to other application. I used following web.config in both applications

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" cookieless="false" timeout="20"
    sqlConnectionString="Server=test\SQLEXPRESS;user id=sa;password=xxx;Application Name=MVC"/>
<machineKey validationKey="someKey" decryptionKey="someOtherKey" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
```

Finally I hosted two applications in same IIS, its working fine session is sharing. But I hosted first application in one web server and second application another IIS the session is not sharing.

Anyone experienced on the session sharing on different application.
please share your thoughts

Comment: Are you using [Configure SQL Server to Store ASP.NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604)??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sharing SQL Server Session State across Web Applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130239/sharing-sql-server-session-state-across-web-applications)

Comment: Exactly. I used the same configuration. so only its working for me while I host in same server

Comment: You need to [use the same machine key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868316/sharing-sessions-across-applications-using-the-asp-net-session-state-service/3151315#3151315)

Comment: @Liam Yes am used same machine key in my both applications. See the above web.config

Comment: And you've tweaked the SP?

Comment: Yes Liam. I changed procedure to store same AppName in ASPStateTempApplications table