# Share same SessionId between two asp.net web applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I used a sql server session mode between two web applications. 
The session id is created in the ASPState database. I need to share the session id from first application to second without using querystring and cookies. I followed the steps from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868316/sharing-sessions-across-applications-using-the-asp-net-session-state-service). Below is the code. 
In both apps **(web.config)**

```
<add name="DBConnection" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;DataBase=ASPState;Integrated Security=True;uid=sa;pwd=password-1" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

<sessionState mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="DBConnection" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" regenerateExpiredSessionId="false" cookieless="false" timeout="1" ></sessionState>         

<machineKey validationKey="566A547C407CB0C47ABAEC581B8B90C45E15039806352E4611B35E0FB70C1C096350A4BBAE816191331DCA55874D3F96B41FFDED4C6A913591684A90825F53A0" decryptionKey="B299127DFC22648C2EF92D7EDF2E4960277F562C60F3BDE4A4C3BFDFEA602FDF" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">    
<add name="BasicAuthenticationModule" type="UserAuthenticator" />
</modules>
```

In first app **Home.aspx.cs**

```
protected void imgBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string sessionKey = HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID;
  //How to transfer the same session id to the second application
   Response.Redirect("http://localhost:43392/PartnerHome.aspx"");
}
```

I got the session key from ASPState database. But how to pass from the same session id to the second application ?

Comment: Does the 2nd app run on the same Server (host) ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman The 2nd app is hosted in different server.

Comment: You can POST the session key to specific page in second application.

Comment: @VinayC : how to post the session key to specific page. any example.

Comment: @kk1076, use `WebClient` or `WebRequest` - you will find plenty of examples for doing POST requests with either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SessionManager to set the ID to whatever you want in the target site. You just need to pass it via querystring GET or form POST from one to the other:

Source

```
Response.Redirect("http://localhost:43392/PartnerHome.aspx?SessID="
    + Session.SessionID);
```

Target

```
string sessionId = Request.QueryString["SessId"];
bool redirected = false;
bool isAdded = false;
new System.Web.SessionState.SessionIDManager().SaveSessionID(
    HttpContext.Current, sessionId, out redirected, out isAdded);
```

See [SessionIDManager on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionidmanager.aspx)

Comment: Is it possible without using querystring

Comment: Not sure. you would probably need to let the page load in the first app, then use javascript to post a form with the sessionid in a hiddenfield to the other site. It's messy and POST doesn't really give you much more security than GET