# Sharing of Session between 2 web application in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-state

I want sharing of session between my 2 web application.web config of my both application have same machineKey but it is not working for sharing of session.Is there any other options?

Answer (score 0):

Check this, it is possible but not recommended. You need to use sessionState SQLServer to achieve this.

[Sharing sessions across applications using the ASP.NET Session State Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868316/sharing-sessions-across-applications-using-the-asp-net-session-state-service)

But i would suggest creating a table and store values in that and access it in old fashioned way. Ultimately sessionState SQLServer is also doing the same thing.

Comment: Is there any other option without using db.

Comment: @user1939371 you have to store values somewhere, either DB or file system as a XML or a flat text file. And if you try to write a file in ASP.NET, security restrictions and Impersonaitions complexities will come into play.

Comment: Create a table and name it something like CrossAppSession("key", "value") store your cross app session in this and remove the entries using relevant logic.

Comment: with the help of SQL Server  session State how this is possible?

Comment: If you read the link provided it states some hacky way to achive it, BUT there is a comment of using it seeing that the session keys are not getting cleared and DB growing huge.

Comment: its means this work is not good through Sql Server session state