# Session sharing between MVC site and webform asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session, httpcookie

I have two websites on in MVC and other in web form (I know it doesn't make any difference but just for information).

I want to share sessions between these two

**What I have tried so far:**

1. Storing session on database on both site in sqlserver session database (with same name)
2. Using same application pool for both site in IIS
3. Using same httpcookie in web config on both site
4. `statserver` for session too

But I'm still not able to share session. Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: Why are you using sessions in a MVC application. MVC is by design stateless. Using Session variable in an ASP.NET MVC application is a bit like tying a horn to a horse's head, and calling it a Unicorn.

Comment: your solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868316/sharing-sessions-across-applications-using-the-asp-net-session-state-service