# Sharing ASP.NET session info between applications in a single application pool and worker process

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

Can ASP.NET applications in a common application pool share session information if they are in separate threads in a single worker process? One of my applications is having issues related to not having any of the session information it needs from the other application, but I used Trace.axd to confirm that requests to each application are using the same session identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved the issues we were experiencing by making our applications "cookieless".
I updated the web.config file for the applications as follows:

```
<!--sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="30" /-->
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="true" timeout="30" />
```

If anyone can explain *why* this works, I would appreciate the education.

Thank you to all who offered suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET session is scoped "within" application if using out-of-the-box session providers, so each application will have its own session even if the session id/key value appears to be the same. But since the requests to each application are using the same session identifier value, you appear to be well set to implement a custom `SessionStateStoreProvider` that can store/retrieve data using this identifier across both applications.

You could also have a look at [Sharing sessions across applications using the ASP.NET Session State Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868316/sharing-sessions-across-applications-using-the-asp-net-session-state-service/3151315#3151315), but since this approach involves modifying the workings of the stock SQL session store provider, you'd risk spillover effects on other sites/applications.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I'll research this further.

Answer (score 0):

I thik it could be helpfull [Sharing Aspnet Session across different domains](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/576989/Sharing-ASP-NET-Web-Applications-Session-State) there's no other way.
you cannot share  a session between different domain.

there's another solution that could be pass all data via querystring to the other domain so it can rebuild the right session values.

Personally i will invite you to use encrypted value to be sure that are not visibile if you will choose GET option.