# IIS SQL Server Session state error

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, iis

I am trying to add session state to SQL Server and I am unable to get it to work.

I first tried adding following connection string into the config:

```
 sessionState mode="SQLServer"
 sqlConnectionString="Server=XXXXXX;Database=ASPState;Integrated Security=true"
```

And get the following error:

> The sqlConnectionString attribute or the connection string it refers to cannot contain the connection options `Database`, `Initial Catalog` or `AttachDbFileName`. In order to allow this, allowCustomSqlDatabase attribute must be set to true and the application needs to be granted unrestricted SqlClientPermission. Please check with your administrator if the application does not have this permission.

I then tried adding `allowCustomSqlDatabase="true"` to the connection string and get the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'tempdb.dbo.ASPStateTempApplications'.

This looks like it is trying to connect to the `tempdb` and not `ASPState` database.

Any ideas how to get this to use the ASPState database?

Cheers

Andy

Comment: Use  Aspnet_regsql.exe to create the database for stateserver. Check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862(v=vs.140).aspx)

Comment: The database has been created. The secord error seems like it is trying to use the tempdb database and not the ASPState database.

Comment: Yes thats what it does, check this [KB](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604/EN-US) and this [KB](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/311209/EN-US) article

Comment: Does it help, using persistent state exe?

Comment: Yeah persistent state exe create the session state database but I am unable to set the session state in IIS to use this database. Which is the error I was getting before. I can only seem to get it to work using tempdb

Comment: @AndrewBeal I update my solution and explained how to add session tables to your database: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49218168/5675763

Answer (score 1):

As it said [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2527105/how-to-share-session-state-across-subdomains):

> If you do not add session state to SQL Server, you receive the following error message that is generated by the System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException class when you configure a website to use SQL Server mode session state:
>
> Invalid object name 'tempdb.dbo.ASPStateTempSessions'.

So you should follow the instruction of Step 1 in the above link and use `aspnet_regsql.exe` to generate required table and other things.

The tool's full path is:

```
<system drive>:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\<.NETFrameworkversion>\aspnet_regsql.exe
```

Take a look at this too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3151315/5675763

## Impotrant Update

from [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carloc/2008/03/05/unable-to-use-sql-server-because-asp-net-version-2-0-session-state-is-not-installed-on-the-sql-server/):

> If you use aspnet_regsql wizard, session tables are not added by default so you need to run the following command...

The command in the above link is this:

```
aspnet_regsql.exe -S <servername> -E -ssadd -sstype p
```

This command will add AspState Database and uses current windows logon.

**If you want to add session state tables and stored procedures to your database** you should use this command:

```
aspnet_regsql.exe -S <server_address> -U <sql_username> -P <sql_password> -d <database_name> -ssadd -sstype c
```

You can use this [command reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862(vs.80).aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_3) to use more options.