# Visual Studio MVC C# and VB Web Forms in Same Solution Sharing Session

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, visual-studio

I have a MVC c# app and I have been tasked with adding in an existing VB .NET web forms app. I have added it to the project and configured it as an application in IIS.  The app works fine except I need to share data between them. An example would be that it is required that the user signs into the c# app and not have to do it again in the VB app. I also need to share the session between the two. When I configure the VB app as a Virtual Directory, I get an exception; 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' in System.Web.dll("").

The project is configured like [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/307467/how-to-create-an-asp.net-application-from-multiple-projects-for-team-development) where it is says Make Multiple Visual Studio .NET Projects Participate in the Same Web Application. [This is a good example of what I am trying](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/8129/separating-an-asp-net-web-application-into-multipl).

I have tried everything that I can find on Google that involves running multiple projects together and running C# MVC and VB Webforms.

Is sharing the session possible? If so, what approach should I take? All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check the solution in the link, it seems you will have to use SQL Server to store the session so both web apps could access it.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868316/sharing-sessions-across-applications-using-the-asp-net-session-state-service

Comment: Thank you so much MAlvarez, that was exactly it. I don't know how I didn't see that after all of the hours that I spent Thursday & Friday of last week looking. Thanks again, this was a life and sanity saver.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sharing sessions across applications using the ASP.NET Session State Service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868316/sharing-sessions-across-applications-using-the-asp-net-session-state-service)

Answer (score 0):

After implementing what I found in the link that was posted by MAlavez above, everything is working as expected. Here's the link in case anyone missed it above. [Sharing sessions across applications using the ASP.NET Session State Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868316/sharing-sessions-across-applications-using-the-asp-net-session-state-service)