# How to deploy Asp.Net MVC application under Asp.Net classic application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an Asp.Net MVC application which i want to deploy under the Asp.NET Classic (Form based) application. In IIS i have an Web Application which is a Root Site. Under that Root site i have one more application which is Child1. In that Child1 i wanted to deploy MVC 5.0 application by creating a Folder. The reason to create a Folder is that I am using the Session variables of Child1 site in my MVC application. So, if i create a SubSite/Virtual Directory then Sessions will not be accessible.

Is there any way to deploy MVC app in ASP.NET Classic app as a SubFolder?

***NOTE: Root and Child1 are ASP.NET Claasic (Form based) application.***

Comment: Somehow I don't sharing session is as simple as installing in a subfolder. There's an alternative solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868316/sharing-sessions-across-applicatins-using-the-asp-net-session-state-service.