# IIS httpredirect causing session null

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, iis-express

When website default domain redirect through httpredirect to hosted application page. In application when button open some page in new tab then session got null.

Comment: Might be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868316/sharing-sessions-across-applications-using-the-asp-net-session-state-service

Comment: Issue not related to given solution link